# C Programming on storage of bits in byte

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a = 128;
    char b = -128;
    printf("a is %d -- b is %d \n",a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
a is -128 -- b is -128
```

As the signed character range is from 0 to 127, from the above code can you please explain how the value is assigned for the out of boundary values.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why would the signed character range be from 0 to 127? The signed character range is from -128 to 127.

Comment: Behavior when there is an overflow is not defined.

Comment: More specifically, the behavior of *signed* overflow is undefined in the C standard, but that of signed overflow is defined.  This is likely related to the standard not specifically requiring that signed values be implemented in 2's complement form (though that is by far the most common implementation)

Answer (score 4):

The range of a `char` type depends on the implementation. If it is a signed type, then its range is at least from -128 to 127, and if it is an unsigned type its range is at least from 0 to 255 (these are the ranges that the type must support at a bare minimum, the range supported by the type may actually be larger than this depending on the implementation).

Also note, that when you assign an integer to a signed type that cannot hold that value, you are invoking *undefined behaviour*. So assigning 128 to a signed char that cannot hold 128 (e.g. when 128 is greater than `CHAR_MAX`) is invoking undefined behaviour. In this case, it has wrapped around to `-128` because it shares the same byte representation as an unsigned char type holding 128, but as with all instances of undefined behaviour, you cannot guarantee that this will be the case on all implementations.

Comment: Stricly speaking you're wrong. `char` is always 1 byte, but the C standard doesn't say that a byte must be 8 bits. So your numbers -128 to 127 aren't really correct (not that I have ever seen a platform with CHAR_BIT != 8, but yeah).

Comment: It's ultimately unsafe to assume that a char is an 8 bit type - certain TI DSP's being a relatively current counter-example.  Yes, that's a special purpose device, but relatively general purpose code can in most other respects be easily ported to and from it, something I've seen happen quite a bit when reshuffling the architecture of a larger system or replacing a subsystem.

Comment: what happens when we  try to assign value 130 and -130 for the variables a and b for the above prototype code?

Comment: @Sailesh - What happens when you try it?  Experiment with a variety of values and see if you see the pattern.

Comment: @ Chris : Initially we will see the warning at the compilation. The out put will be O/P : a is -126 -- b is 126
But I just thought of checking out with you how the value will be assigned/stored, so that when accessing what will be result. Actually my concern is to know how the value will be stored or assigned when we are trying to assign out of boundary values to the variables.

Comment: @nightcracker: I mentioned in my answer that -128 to 127 is the range that a signed char type must support *at a bare minimum*, as in, the signed char type *must* be able to represent these values. Whether is supports a greater range is up to the implementation. Nothing I have said here is wrong.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I haven't said anywhere that a char type is 8 bits. I said it was *at least* 8 bits (by saying it must be able to hold the range -128 to 127 at a bare minimum).

Comment: @dreamlax: I totally skipped over the bare minimum part, I'm sorry.

Comment: Supplemental:  
only "char" mean "signed char" or "unsigned char".

Comment: @dreamlax sorry I didn't see the minimum either